# Global variable keeps overwriting session variable

Tags: php, session

Below is a simple test code that I've produced from a bug I am facing right now.

```
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
else
$_SESSION['views'] = 1;

$views = "hi";
echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views'];
```

from what i believe `$views` and `$_SESSION['views']` are completely different things. On a local test the script gives proper response first time 1 then 2 and then 3 and on and on.

The bug only exist on ipage hosting, [there](http://prometaclients.be/testsession.php) the same code gives output `hi` each time.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in theory `$views` and `$_SESSION['views']` should be completely different things. However, there used to be a setting called `register_globals` in PHP. It has been marked as deprecated in version 5.3.0 and was removed from version 5.4.0, but people were using that quite a lot, because then you don't have to worry about superglobals and all that more involved stuff and can instead just type pretty much whatever you want.

Anyway. Try to find out if your host is using an older version of PHP and if this function is activated on the server. I bet it is. Easiest way to do it: put the following script on the server and search for `register_globals`:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: `register_globals` has been removed quite some time ago, on 5.4.0.

Comment: Ah thanks. I'm not really up-to-date on the most recent versions. ;)

Comment: @TillHelge thanks a lot, i see register_globals is `on` on server

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ Then you probably should start nagging your hoster to update to a more recent version of PHP. Some hosters even used to have a way in the admin panel to turn it off. It's really useless and bad to have this "feature" enabled.

Comment: yes actually this hosting has a lot more issues related to sessions. This one included, it just wasted 3 hours me to debug what was wrong, they have provided access to php.ini though.